# Passportjs exclude resources

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm working an API endpoint with expressjs and protecting it with passportjs (using jwt strategy)

I have

```
 passport.use(new JwtStrategy({...})) // Register stratrgy

 router.post('/login', (req, res) => {} ) // Generates jwt token

 app.use('/api', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }));

 app.user('/api', router) // Register the route to /api
```

If I put `/login` out of `/api`, this works just fine. But I want to have some resource like `/login` in the same root path (`/api`) to be not protected.

I can go ahead and add `passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false })` to every route registration except the unprotected once, but I don't like that.

I can also create a middleware that call `passport.authenticate` manually and check other things, but I would like to avoid re-inventing the wheel if it is already done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried creating a route like:

`app.post('/api/login')`

And then after that you define your router like:

`app.user('/api', router) // Register the route to /api`

Finally inside your router file, at the top, you do

`router.use(passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }))`

Comment: You mean to use different routers for authenticated and unauthenticated requests?